# How to call the method of HashMap from another class?

Tags: java, class, methods, hashmap

In my assessment class, I have a method called addMark and it puts both studentid and mark into the hashmap called marks. I'm trying to put studentid and mark into the hashmap using student class but it keeps on giving me errors. Am I calling the assessment class wrongly? Can someone please help?

Student class:

```
public class Student {
 public void createStudents() {
   Mark m1 = new Mark(30, "Bad");
   Assessment.addMark("11", m1);
}
```

Mark class:

```
public class Mark {

private int mark;
private String comment;

public Mark(int mark){

}

public Mark(int mark, String comment){

}

public void setMark(int mark) throws Exception {
    /*
     * Start Preconditions
     */
    // Precondition: firstArgumentNonNegative
    if (mark < 0){
        throw new Exception("Precondition violated:"
                + " firstArgumentNonNegative");
    }
    /*
     * End Preconditions
     */
    this.mark = mark;
}

public int getMark() {
    return this.mark;
}

public void setComment(String comment){
    this.comment = comment;
}

public String getComment(){
    return this.comment;
}
}
```

Assessment class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public abstract class Assessment {
private Map<String, Mark> marks = new HashMap<String, Mark>();


public String getAllStudentMarks(){
    String outString = "Student ID:\tMark:\tComment:";
    for (Map.Entry<String, Mark> entry : marks.entrySet()){
        String studentId = entry.getKey();
        Mark mark = entry.getValue();
        int value = mark.getMark();
        String comment = mark.getComment();
        outString += String.format("\n%s\t%d\t%s", studentId, value, comment);
    }
    return outString;
}

public boolean hasCompleted(String studentId){
    return marks.containsKey(studentId);
}


public void addMark(String studentId, Mark mark) throws Exception{
    /*
     * Start Preconditions
     */
    // Precondition: markNotGreaterThanWeight
    if (mark.getMark() > this.weight){
        throw new Exception("Precondition violated: "
                + "markNotGreaterThanWeight");
    }
    /*
     * End Preconditions
     */
    marks.put(studentId, mark);
}

public int getMark(String studentId){
    return marks.get(studentId).getMark();
}

public String getComment(String studentId){
    return marks.get(studentId).getComment();
}   

public abstract String description();
}
```

Comment: What errors ? at compile time or at run time ?

Comment: method `addMark` is not static, so you need to call it via an object, not a class name

Comment: also you can't do `this.weight` in `Assessment`, it does not have a weight property

Comment: your Assessment class is abstract, you will need to extend it to use it.

Comment: Use [IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), not Exception.  (Forcing callers to catch Exception will cause the many unchecked exceptions which indicate programmer errors to be suppressed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Assessment` is an abstract class so you will need to extend it if you want to use it:

```
class MyAssessment extends Assessment {
    @Override
    public String description() {
       return "My assessment";
    } 
}
```

Then you can call `addMark` on this new implementation

```
MyAssessment myAssessment = new MyAssessment();
myAssessment.addMark("11", m1);
```

Also this method throws an `Exception` so you need to try/catch it

```
try {
    new MyAssessment().addMark("11", m1);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And finally you have no `weight` property in your `Assessment` class so you should somehow define one if you want the class to compile.

```
private int weight = 0;
```

Comment: Can I ask what does @Override do? Thank you :)

Comment: the `@Override` annotation says that you want this implementation of the `description()` method to replace the one of the parent class (`Assessment`). In this specific case you need to do it because the parent class has a `description()` method which is `abstract` and has no implementation, so you have to provide one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to get the exact question but through your code, I found.

1. You need to extend abstract class `Assessment` ex. `AssessmentManager`

   ```
   class AssessmentManager extends Assessment
   ```
2. Create an object of `AssessmentManager`  and then use it.

   ```
   AssessmentManager _assessment = new AssessmentManager();
   _assessment.addMark(Student_ID, Marks)
   ```

Comment: You'll probably want to save the object somewhere (in a variable), else it will get Garbage Collected.